# How to connect to db4free,net mysql database using google scripts

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script

I tried the below code to fetch records from db4free mysql db and write to google sheet. but i get the following error "Check connection string, username and password."
Can you please help me to connect to db4free? i can connect to other free online DBs but they only offer 5MB. where as db4free offer 200MB.

Please see the code below.

```
function readFromDB() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://db4free.net:3306;databaseName="cricketgame","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from UserList");

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.create('data');
  var cell = doc.getRange('a1');
  var row = 0;
  while(rs.next()) {
    cell.offset(row, 0).setValue(rs.getString(1));
    cell.offset(row, 1).setValue(rs.getString(2));
    row++;
  }
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

db4free.net offers MySQL servers not MSSQL. So your connection url should start with `jdbc:mysql` not `jdbc:sqlserver`.

Comment: I tried the below as well `var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306;databaseName="cricketgame","USERNAME","PASSWORD");` and also `var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://db4free.net;databaseName="cricketgame","USERNAME","PASSWORD");` still not able to connect. Thanks for the response. Please help.

Comment: @udaykumar Signed up for a db4free account and after running some tests it appears that establishing a connection just takes too long and Apps Script's JDBC connector times out as a result. There is no work-around for that unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please share what you tried? So that I too can try from my end. Thanks for helping out. I really appreciate for the time.

Comment: @udaykumar Nothing to share really. I used a commercial database client (Navicat) to connect to db4free's mysql server and it took a very long time to establish a connection (at least 45 seconds!). When I attempted to connect with GAS I got an error after about 20 seconds. I suspect that Apps Script's JDBC connection has a lower time limit to establish a connection hence why it probably fails.

Answer (score 0):

in time, the Google connection does not support version 8.0 of mysql. Works perfectly with 5.7 . The mysql of db4free.net have 8.0 version.